# Compare a Variable to a Data Type in C++

Tags: c++, string, io, getline, stdstring

I'd like to know if there is a concise method for comparing a variable to a data type.

The following example is not a functioning piece of code, but the comment and the code below the comment should explain my question:

```
string inputString = "";
float inputFloat = 0.0;

cout << "Input a string: ";

getline(cin, inputString);
stringstream(inputString) >> inputFloat;

// Is there a way to compare a float variable to a string or float data type? 
if(inputFloat == string) { 
    cout << "inputFloat is not a float" << endl;
} else if(inputFloat == float) {
    cout << "inputFloat is a float!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: When `inputFloat` should be equal to `float` or `string`?

Comment: It says `float inputFloat`. That's pretty unambiguous: it's a `float`. Also, since C++ does not have a base class type, and since built-in data types like `float` aren't objects...

Comment: The `typeid` keyword might help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is just a simple check of return value of `std::getline` and `operator>>`:

```
std::cout << "Input a string: ";
std::string inputString = "";
float inputFloat = 0.0;
if (std::getline(std::cin, inputString) && 
    std::istringstream(inputString) >> inputFloat)  {
    std::cout << "Succesfully read float: " << inputFloat;
}
else {
    // TODO: either getline failed to read string or >> failed to extract float
}
```

note that `std::istringstream(inputString) >> inputFloat` constructs a temporary string stream and uses the appropriate overload of `>>` designed specially to extracting `float` values from it. Checking the return value additionally ensures that by the time the `inputFloat` is outputted, it has been successfully retrieved from the stream and contains valid value.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
stringstream(inputString) >> inputFloat;
```

When you do this, you are calling an `operator>>(istream, float)`, so you either succeed to read a float there, or fail and load nothing. You can check for `.fail()` on the stringstream object to verify that.

Since you're calling that specific overload of `operator>>`, there's no possibility that you "loaded a variable of different type" into the `inputFloat` variable, or anything like that.